# How to remove the datetime suffix and increment # from the produced maven artifact from mvn clean deploy?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, maven-3, maven-plugin

I have an `Spring Boot` based `java` application which is producing a `JAR` artifact when I run `mvn clean install` with the name `my-nexus-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`.

But when I do `mvn clean deploy` I see `my-nexus-demo-0.0.1-20190806.161150-1.jar` deployed in my local filesystem (will be using `Nexus` in the future). Not sure why it is appending datetime and increment # as suffix when I am using `mvn clean deploy` command.

I have already mentioned `<finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>` in my `pom` and also specified `<uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>` as well.

I have couple of questions here:

1. How can I have the consistent artifact name across `.m2` and both `SNAPSHOT` and `RELEASE` repos?
2. What's the best practice that a developer should following while building and deploying artifacts? Shouldn't the artifacts names be consistent throughout?

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-nexus-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>my-nexus-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>pet-projects-snapshot-repo</id>
            <name>My Local Nexus Snapshots Repository</name>
            <url>file://I/.m2/my-nexus/pet-projects-snapshot-repo</url>
            <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

</project>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you describe is the expected behaviour. Locally, as Snapshot version is just saved with the suffix `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` while on a remote repository (the one you `deploy` to), Snapshot versions are saved with timestamps. This doesn't really matter, though, because if you request a dependency with version `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`, Maven is smart enough to give you the latest timestamp version for that particular version number. So it is really not much more than an implementation detail.

When your artifact is ready for production, you build a *Release* version (e.g. with the maven-release-plugin) and get a version number without SNAPSHOT or timestamp.

Comment: That answers my question, Thanks !